# Search within syntax group?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, search

Is there a way to take advantage of syntax highlighting for searches? For example, can a search be limited to comments or non-comments, if they are correctly marked by syntax highlighting?

Comment: Your question may be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683521/vim-search-in-c-c-code-lines

Comment: Also see my post on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35323962/2072269. It's limited to excluding comments which can be folded, though.