# Is there a way to restrict search results to differences in a diff?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, search

I want to be able to search only within the `DiffText` regions of a file that I'm editing.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683521/vim-search-in-c-c-code-lines

The accepted answer here seems to work great for say, `Comment` or `Type` syntax groups, but any of the Diff groups don't work. I surmise it something to do with the diff groups being nested within other groups.

My specific scenario is that I've removed a bunch of tabs and trailing spaces from a bunch of files. I've diffed the files with the originals and want to make sure that nothing except tabs and trailing spaces are different.

P.S. I don't want to do a global replace of all the tabs because my predecessor used inconsistent indentation and I need to manually check all of it.

Comment: `:set diffopt+=iwhite`, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that *would* work for my specific scenario. Thanks! However, I would still be interested to know if there is a way to restrict search results for other possible scenarios.

Comment: Related post: [Search within syntax group?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7749/search-within-syntax-group)

Comment: That post links to the Q I posted. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not natively (also I have written a patch, that would allow to add a skip expression to the search() function, but this hasn't been included yet).

But you can workaround it by writing your own function that checks, whether the match is in a diff region contained. Something like this (very basic approach):

```
function! Search(pat)
    while search(a:pat, 'w') > 0
        if diff_hlID(line('.'),col('.')) != 0
            break
        endif
    endwhile
endfunction

com! -nargs=1 Search :call Search(<q-args>)
```

Error checking and handling more edge cases (abort after the search has wrapped around, eg.) left as excercise to the user.

Comment: Man, vim is huge; didn't even know diff_hlID existed. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Only, unless I understand something wrong, I think your if statement should be `if... != 0` So that it breaks from searching when it lands on a diff. That's what seemed to work for me at lest. (I know your function wasn't intended to be complete, but I'm pretty sure this is backwards.)

Comment: @Tumbler41 I think this you are correct.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Mind editing for future readers? :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the simple way to search the differences (all
different lines, not just DiffText, sorry) would be to run
`diff` on the two files, put the output in a buffer and
search there. Assuming you're viewing filea and fileb in
vimdiff:

```
:new | r! diff -u0 filea fileb
/search-for-something
```

Line numbers will be in the output, in lines like

```
@@ -9,3 +8,6 @@
```

so you could easily jump
to the line (9) in the original file:

```
?@@<CR>0/\d<CR>yw:q!:@"<CR>
```

This searches backwards for a line-number line, yanks the line number into
@", closes the temporary search buffer, and jumps to the line number. You'll probably
want to massage that to take into account your window
layout, etc., and maybe map it to a key.

You could also include context lines in the diff, to make it easier read, but make sure that your searches look in lines with changes, i.e. those that start with a non-blank:

```
/^\S.*\zssearch-for-something
```

Comment: Ah, a filtering approach. Not quite what I had in mind, but I can get behind this. Still trying to fully understand your macro though. My header lines are in the form of: `@@ -292,2 +283,7 @@`. That being said, I can't quite figure out what the `0/` is for in your search pattern. Additionally `yW` will yank the WORD, meaning `292,2`. When you execute `:@"` This takes you to line 2 instead of 292. I think I would come up with something like this: `?@@.*+?e+1<CR>yw:q!<CR>:@"<CR>`. You could change the first  `+` to `-` depending on which file you wanted to look at. Thoughts?

Comment: Oops, typo there, sorry. Edited.

Comment: There was a missing `<CR>` to terminate the search pattern, and the `yW` should be `yw` like you said!

Comment: Yeah, those look like good suggestions to me. You could have two mappings, depending on which file you wanted to jump to, or you could work that out automatically from the `+` or `-` at the start of the line and the filenames in the header.